# Regular expression: replace word except if followed by dash

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

How to replace "cat" in a given string by "FELIX" but not if it's followed by special character like "- or _ or :"

example :

"my cat is hungry all the time" => "my Felix is hungry all the time"

"the products cat-1547 and cat:154 are disponible now"
 => "the products cat-1547 and cat:154 are disponible now"

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use a negative lookahead together with word boundaries:

```
/\bcat\b(?![-:])/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yC6fZ8/1)

**Pattern explanation**:

- `\b` - leading word boundary (to avoid matching `cat` in `tomcat`)
- `cat` - a literal string `cat`
- `\b` - trailing word boundary (i.e. the next char must be a non-letter, non-digit and non-underscore character, and it prevents from matching `cat` in `catwalk`)
- `(?![-:])` - a *negative lookahead* that fails the match if a `-` or `:` *immediately* follows the `cat`.

[PHP demo](https://ideone.com/ZVaQUh):

```
$re = '~\bcat\b(?![-:])~'; 
$str = "my cat is hungry all the time\nthe products cat-1547 and cat:154 are disponible now"; 
$subst = "Felix"; 
$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
echo $result;
```

Comment: thank you wiktor it works and also thanks for the Demo

Answer (score 0):

In python you can :

```
(cat)(?![-:])
```

?! checks that the expression isn't followed by what's after ?!